# Why can't I send an int from java to C without waiting?

Tags: java, c, sockets

I'm having a bit of a weird problem. I'm trying to write an interface between a C client and a Java server. To this end I've written a gateway in Java (which communicates with the server using RMI). Almost everything is working, but I'm trying to return some integers from the gateway to the C client. Here's the code:

Java gateway:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.lang.System;

public class hotelgw{

  public static final int PORT = 4242;
  public static final int BACKLOG = 5;
  public static final int MAX_ARGS = 5;

  public hotelgw(){
    InetSocketAddress address;
    ServerSocket socket = null;
    try{
      address = new InetSocketAddress(PORT);
      socket = new ServerSocket(PORT,BACKLOG);
    }catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("Error: "+e);
      System.exit(1);
    }

    while(true){

      Socket newsock = null;
      try{
       newsock =  socket.accept();
      }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
        System.exit(1);
      }

      BufferedReader in = null;
      DataOutputStream out = null;

      try{
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(newsock.getInputStream()));
        out = new DataOutputStream(newsock.getOutputStream());
      }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
        System.exit(1);
      }


      String[] init_args = new String[MAX_ARGS];
      int i = 0;
      String c;

      try{
        while(!(c = in.readLine()).equals("end")){
          System.out.printf("%s",c);
          init_args[i] = c;
          i++;
        }
      }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
        System.exit(1);
      }

      for(int j=0;j<init_args.length;j++){
        System.out.printf("init_args[%d] = %s\n", j, init_args[j]);
      }

      int counter = 0;
      for(int j=0;j<init_args.length;j++){
        if(init_args[j] != null){
          counter++;
        }
      }

      String[] final_args = new String[counter];
      for(int j=0;j<counter;j++){
        final_args[j] = init_args[j];
      }

      if(final_args[1].equals("list")){
        int[] list = hotelclient.get_list(final_args);
        System.out.println("list received in hotelgw.java");
        for(int j=0;j<list.length;j++){
          try{
            out.writeInt(list[j]);
          }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error writing to socket: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
          }
        }
      }


      try{
        in.close();
        newsock.close();
      }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
        System.exit(1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

C client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 4242
#define TYPES_OF_ROOMS 3
#define BUFFER_SIZE 64

/*Writes message to socket*/
ssize_t writen(int fd, const void *vptr, size_t n)
{
  size_t nleft;
  ssize_t nwritten;
  const int *ptr;

  ptr = vptr;
  nleft = n;
  while(nleft>0){
    if ( ((nwritten = write(fd,ptr,nleft)) <= 0)){
      if (errno == EINTR)
        nwritten = 0;
      else
        return -1;

    }
    nleft -= nwritten;
    ptr += nwritten;
  }
  return n;
}


int create_socket(char* address){
  struct hostent *server_address;
  struct in_addr *addr;
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
  socklen_t addrlen;
  char* ip;

  int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(sockfd<0){
    perror("Error creating socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  server_address = gethostbyname(address);
  if(server_address == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Server not found!\n");
    exit(1);
  }else{
    addr = (struct in_addr*) server_address->h_addr_list[0];
  }

  ip = inet_ntoa(*addr);

  server_addr.sin_family  =  AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_port    =  htons(PORT);
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr  =  inet_addr(ip); 

  addrlen = (socklen_t) sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

  if(connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, addrlen)){
    perror("Error connecting to server");
    exit(1);
  }

  return sockfd;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
  int sockfd, err, i, type1=0, type2=0, type3=0;
  int int_buf[TYPES_OF_ROOMS];
  char string_buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
  char newline = '\n';
  char *end = "end";

  if(argc == 1){
    printf("Usage: hotelgwclient <address> {list,guests,book} [room type] [guest name]\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  sockfd = create_socket(argv[1]);
  printf("Socket created\n");


  if(strcmp(argv[2], "list")==0){
    if(argc != 3){
      printf("Usage: hotelgwclient <address> list\n");
      exit(1);
    }


    printf("list initiated\n");
    writen(sockfd, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
    writen(sockfd, &newline , sizeof(newline));
    writen(sockfd, argv[2], strlen(argv[2])); 
    writen(sockfd, &newline, sizeof(newline));
    writen(sockfd, end, strlen(end));
    writen(sockfd, &newline, sizeof(newline));
    printf("Written to socket\n");

    err = read(sockfd, &type1, sizeof(int));
    err = read(sockfd, &type2, sizeof(int));
    err = read(sockfd, &type3, sizeof(int));

    printf("Read from socket\n");
    if(err<0){
      perror("Error reading from socket");
      exit(1);
    }
    /*
    for(i=0;i<TYPES_OF_ROOMS;i++){
      printf("%d\t",int_buf[i]);
    }
    */
    type1 = htonl(type1);
    type2 = htonl(type2);
    type3 = htonl(type3);

    printf("%d\t",type1);
    printf("%d\t",type2);
    printf("%d\t",type3);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
  }

  printf("Command not recognized.\nUsage: hotelgwclient <address> {list,guests,book} [room type] [guest name]\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

(N.B. I know it's messy, I'mma clean it up when it works :) ).

The problem is that whenever I call the list method, and C tries to read the respons (three ints) it will only read one byte, not four. This is fixed if I add a sleep() call before reading from the sockets. Does anybody know what's happening and what I should do to fix it?!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what this read() function is, but in C, you must loop on recv() until every byte is received

Comment: Basically, it is always an error if you ignore the result of an input operation (like `read`).

Comment: Yes! The recv() with flag MSG_WAITALL did the trick! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you are assuming you will read as much data as you want when the minimum is always 1 (even in Java)

Why you are getting one byte before the others is that you are using DataOutputStream without a BufferedOutputStream so it is sending one byte at a time.  It might be tempting to use this workaround  but it just hides the underlying problem that you need to be able to read one byte at a time correctly as this is always a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Its valid for `read` to return fewer bytes that you requested.  From its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read):

> Return Value
> On success, the number of bytes read is returned...  It
>   is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes
>   requested; this may happen

You'll need to call `read` in a loop until the expected number of bytes or an error have been returned:

```
unsigned char* p = &type1;
int expected = sizeof(int);
while (expected > 0) {
    err = read(sockfd, p, expected);
    if (err < 0) {
        break;
    }
    p += err;
    expected -= err;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When there are blocking calls involved and must act parallely, you gotta add threads for each task(such as one for reading and another for writing) so that they don't block the execution.

Also put everything received in a buffer and try to parse from there on. Implement threads with pthread api.